# What is a good way to get 0 or a value dependant on a boolean?

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, mathematical-optimization

I'm currently working on a piece of code that quite simply uses a boolean to see whether the screen is flipped vertically.
This is done with :

```
glOrtho(0.0f, _width, flip ? 0.0f : _height, flip ? _height : 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
```

I was wondering if there would be a more optimized way to do this, for example :

```
glOrtho(0.0f, _width, !flip * _height, flip * _height, -1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Or would a bitwise operation work?

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: Is optimization really a concern here given that a screen flip is a relatively rare occurrance?

Comment: i would assume, that a smart compiler would optimize that anyway.

Comment: As this function is called very rarely (even if called once per frame its just outweighted by so much things), it quite an unusual place for optimization. I don not know if it's that good to trade a small jump for a float multiplication. But you could also reinterpret `_height` as int and & it with `flip` and `-flip` repsectively.

Comment: As I said, it was more of a hypothetical question, I guess I should have asked the question differently, but in any case I'll just check out what the compiler does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure that this is a bottleneck in your program?? Don't early optimize and obfuscate your code just for a small gain.

Comment: +1.  Absolutely.  At any rate, it's quite possible that the compiler will find a better optimisation than a multiply for this.  Let it do its job.

Comment: I understand the necessity for code lisibility, I guess it was more of a hypothetical question.
I guess I'll check out compiler optimizations later just out of interest.
Thanks for the quick reply :).

Answer (score 1):

In general, `boolValue ? floatValue : 0.0f` is equal to `boolValue * floatValue`

Comment: Yes, but is one faster than the other?

Comment: @Oli: Probably, given that the trinary operator is essentially a conditional statement, but not enough that I would be concerned about it.

Comment: @Oli: In general, I believe the first one should be faster as it is `testb` essentially, and the second involves floating point math.

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko: It's _very_ implementation-dependent (not all CPU's have `testb`), but floating-point math is generally cheaper than a memory load.

Comment: I guess it all depends, right? If that stuff is already in register, testing boolean and returning float should be faster than FP math, even with MMX stuff. I'm talking mainly about Intel's cores. It should be tested to know for sure. But I don't think it is worse it unless this is a bottleneck, which I doubt.